# My Code stuck in mid while variable is declared - I am new to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, copydataset

> 'my code is to copy data from each sheet in an open workbook and
> paste in its mastedatasheet.

```
Sub CallData()
            
        Dim CorpFile As Worksheet, CopyRg As Range, PasteRg As Range
        
        Set CorpFile = Sheets("MasterData")
        Set CopyRg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set PasteRg = CorpFile.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'it is stuck here
        
        For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook
        
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> CorpFile Then
        
        CopyRg.Copy PasteRg
        
        End If
        
        Next Sheet
        
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CallData()

    Dim CorpFile As Worksheet, sheet As Worksheet
    Dim PasteRg As Range
        
    Set CorpFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterData")
    
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
        If sheet.Name <> CorpFile.Name Then

            Set PasteRg = CorpFile.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            sheet.UsedRange.Copy PasteRg
            
        End If
    
    Next sheet
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you could move your second `Set PasteRg` above the previous line and you wouldn't need the first `Set PasteRg`.

Comment: @Darren Yes that would be smarter. I tried to make minimal changes to the original code so the error with `CorpFile.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` was clear.